# Problema con usuario de conexion entre ssms y VStudio

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

Se me esta generando este error al momento de correr uno de los `controllers` de un proyecto en Visual Studio en este caso 'sa' es el nombre del usuario  q utilizo para conectarme con el servidor `JOSEALEXANDER\SQLEXPRESS` al cual se  conecta la base de datos en `SSMS` lo cual en efecto sucede sin embargo al momento de establecer la conexión desde Visual Studio con la base de datos a través del servidor  genera un error de conexión con el usuario, lo extraño de esto es que en el explorador de servidores puedo visualizar los SP de la `BD` no así las tablas como puedo hacer para crear otro usuario con el cual poder establecer otra conexión para intentar correr de  nuevo el el `controller`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error de servidor en la aplicación `'/'`.

> Login failed for user 'sa'. Descripción: Excepción no controlada al
>   ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila
>   para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el
>   código.

Detalles de la excepción:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'.

Error de código fuente:

> Línea 22:         { Línea 23:             ///obtenemos los registros
>   de la tabla dbo.Course Línea 24:             List listaCourses
>   = this.entidadSchoolDatabase.Course.ToList(); Línea 25:             ///lo asiganamos al objeto ViewBag para poder accederlo en la vista
>   Línea 26:             ///recordar que el objeto ViewBag es dinamico
>   para case sensitive

Archivo de origen:

> C:\Users\Jose Alexander\Desktop\Documentos Jose Alexander\Programacion
>   VI\Laboratorio3\EjemploEF\EjemploEF\Controllers\CargaControlesDemoController.cs
>   Línea: 24

Seguimiento de la pila:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
>   sqlAuthProviderManager) +907
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +334
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +699
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +89
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +191
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +90
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +443    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection
>   t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +12
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +405
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.b__2() +71
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +15
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +190
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation) +82
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +271
>
> [EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +334
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean
>   shouldMonitorTransactions) +132
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +46
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>   +154    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +190
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +283
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   +15    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +387
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>
>   EjemploEF.Controllers.CargaControlesDemoController.CargaDropDownList()
>   in C:\Users\Jose Alexander\Desktop\Documentos Jose
>   Alexander\Programacion
>   VI\Laboratorio3\EjemploEF\EjemploEF\Controllers\CargaControlesDemoController.cs:24
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
>   +228    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9874041    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
>
> Información de versión: Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319;
>   Versión ASP.NET:4.7.3282.0